# How to create a generic function for methods like click in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to create a generic click functions in testcafe so that we can reuse the same click method for scenarios like button or checkbox

I am not finding generic click method in testcafe

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand you. There is an existing method that you can use to click different elements - `click`: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402710/reference/test-api/testcontroller/click

If you want to create your custom click functions, there is no special mechanism yet, but you can use a simple function for this, for example:

```js
async function customClick (t, selector) {
  //...actions
  await t.click(selector);
  //...actions
}

fixture('Getting Started')
    .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example');

test('My first test', async t => {
    await customClick(t, Selector('#remote-testing'))
});
```